# Proving equivalence of two definitions of "dense" in $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis

Ok, so I've been trying to learn how to write proofs and I've been given this definition for DENSE:

D is dense in $R$ if for each x $\in$ $R$, $\exists$ {${d_n}$}$_{n=1}{^\infty}$ $\in$ D with $\lim_{n \to \infty} d_n$ = x

How would I go about starting to prove this? Is there a particular method that would be easiest?

EDIT: This is another definition I was given.

A set D $\subseteq R$ is DENSE if for each a < b, a,b $\in R$, $\exists$ d $\in$ D with a < d < b

Comment: Is that your definition of "dense"?  You can't prove a definition.  However, you can prove the equivalence of two definitions.  Do you know another way to define a "dense" set?  What fact are you trying to prove, and what facts are you starting with?

Comment: Well I was also given this definition.

Comment: You need to prove that both definitions are equivalent??

Comment: Well, if I can't prove a definition, then I guess I need to show equivalence of the two. How do I show the first is equivalent to the second?

Answer (score 1):

The bottom definition is, in English,

> A subset $D$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is dense if every open interval contains a member of $D$.

and the definition you are trying to prove is

> A subset $D$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is dense if every point in $\mathbb{R}$ is the limit of some sequence of elements of $D$.

To prove that these are equivalent, you will have to show that the first implies the second *and* that the second implies the first.

To show that the first implies the second, begin by assuming that we have a set $D$ satisfying the first definition, that is every open interval in $\mathbb{R}$ contains a member of $D$.  Using this information, can you construct some sequence $\{d_n\}$ that converges to a limit $x$?  Perhaps by using a sequence of intervals containing or approaching $x$?

To show that the first implies the second, begin by assuming that every point $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is a limit of some sequence $\{d_n\}$.  If $d_n \rightarrow x$, what can we say about the existence of some $d_i$ in an open interval containing $x$?